# How to connect two dialogs?

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

If i click on one dialog button on the other dialog will show some text, it doesnt have to be text basicly connection between two dialogs.  Something that will help me about my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two QWidget (or inherited) objects represented as dialogs, then you should use an QObject::connect method. Learn about **signals and slots in Qt**. It looks like:

```
class DialogA : public QWidget {
Q_OBJECT
...
public slots:
    void ShowSomeText(); // called when receive a signal
...
};

class DialogB : public QWidget {
Q_OBJECT
...
    void SendTextSignal(); // sends a signal
...
};

// somwhere in code
DialogA da;
DialogB db;
connect(db, SIGNAL(SendTextSignal()), da, SLOT(ShowSomeText()));
```